# How can a country grow with so much debt?

Tags: government-debt

I was going through the Indian budget (Indiabudget.gov.in), and I noticed something very strange. The overall liability of the govt was many times more than the revenue estimated in the budget. How can such an economy grow when the govt has so much debt on itself and it continues to grow over the years. At what level does the debt seem to be dangerous? [image]
[image]